# Call a Struct and its Method by name in Go?

Tags: go, go-reflect

I have found a function call `MethodByName()` here http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MethodByName but it's not exactly what I want! (maybe because I don't know how to use it ... I cannot find any example with it). What I want is:

```
type MyStruct struct {
//some feilds here
} 
func (p *MyStruct) MyMethod { 
    println("My statement."); 
} 

CallFunc("MyStruct", "MyMethod"); 
//print out "My statement."
```

So I guess, first I need something like `StructByName()` and after that use it for `MethodByName()`, is that right!?

Comment: since MyMethod is a method of *MyStruct, I believe you would at least need an instance of *MyStruct to cal MyMethod with. Maybe it's assumed that CallFunc creates a zeroed instaces of MyStruct?

Comment: the hard thing is I don't know the type of the Struct yet!

Comment: Here if you are expecting the
`   CallFunc("MyStruct", "MyMethod");   ` to instanciate the struct and execute the function which need to be an impure function to make sense then only reason you have the * there is to not have a pass by value of huge struct.So in essence the struct would work just as a namespace

Comment: I have posted a number of [helpful examples on using reflection](https://github.com/Xeoncross/go-reflection-examples/).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To call a method on an object, first use `reflect.ValueOf`. Then find the method by name, and then finally call the found method. For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type T struct {}

func (t *T) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}

func main() {
    var t T
    reflect.ValueOf(&t).MethodByName("Foo").Call([]reflect.Value{})
}
```

Comment: The issue in my case Is I cant not declare *t* is typed *T*, its must be some how I can declare *t* typed *T* by the name of *T* is string "T".

Comment: @nvcnvn: I would suggest to match the name against the string "T" somewhere in your code and create a value of type T if the name matched. If it matches some other type "U", create a value of type U. The values can be freely passed around as interface{}.

Comment: Thank you @Atom, what if the method Foo has any arguments? And has any return values?

Comment: ```
func  callMethod(methodName string, reflectValue reflect.Value) {
 // Only get address from non-pointer
 if reflectValue.CanAddr() && reflectValue.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
  reflectValue = reflectValue.Addr()
 }
        if methodValue := reflectValue.MethodByName(methodName);methodValue.IsValid() {
      switch method := methodValue.Interface().(type) {
                    case func():
   method()
                   case func() error:
                       log.LogError(method())
                   ..............
                }
}
```

Comment: this just outputs `[<float64 Value>]` rather than the value returned by the function for me

Answer (score 36):

```
type YourT1 struct {}
func (y YourT1) MethodBar() {
    //do something
}

type YourT2 struct {}
func (y YourT2) MethodFoo(i int, oo string) {
    //do something
}

func Invoke(any interface{}, name string, args... interface{}) {
    inputs := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))
    for i, _ := range args {
        inputs[i] = reflect.ValueOf(args[i])
    }
    reflect.ValueOf(any).MethodByName(name).Call(inputs)
}

func main() {
     Invoke(YourT2{}, "MethodFoo", 10, "abc")
     Invoke(YourT1{}, "MethodBar")
}
```

Really the code needs to check the method's input number and even whether the method itself exists.

You can reference this http://gowalker.org/reflect#Type

1. Check "any" is a struct type
2. Check "any" has "name" method
3. Check the number of method "name" input parameters is equal the length of args
4. Implement `ret` by `reflect.Value.Interface()`

and be careful the Ptr type;

Or you can use `SomeInterface{}` instead of directly using `interface{}` to ensure this "any" type, like this:

```
type Shape interface {
    Area() float64  //some method to ensure any is an Shape type.
}

func Invoke(s Shape, name string, inputs...interface{}) []interface{} {
}
```

so this is OK

```
color := Invoke(Circle{}, "GetColor")[0].(Color)
```

but

```
Invoke(NotAShape{}, "ForBar")
```

can't be compiled because `NotAnShape` isn't a Shape.

If you can't be sure about the first type at compile time, you can build a map to store all possible type, like this:

```
map[string]reflect.Value{
    "YourT1" : reflect.ValueOf(YourT1{})
    "YourT2" : reflect.ValueOf(YourT2{})
    "Circle" : reflect.ValueOf(Cirlce{}) // or reflect.ValueOf(&Circle{})
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the code. How about the method has any return values?

Comment: the return values is more bother becaus you have to manually convert the reflect.Value to your excepted value type.
http://gowalker.org/reflect#Value_Call  will return an array of reflect.Values as return values.   reflect.Value has the method *Interface* which will return the an interface.

Comment: snyh, can you explain it more? I'll be very grateful if you explain how can i convert `[]reflect.Value` here to `error`, because my function has this signature `func doSmth() error {...}`

Comment: @vodolaz095 https://gowalker.org/reflect#Value_Interface


    err := fmt.Errorf("a error example")
    vv := reflect.ValueOf(err)
    s, ok := vv.Interface().(error)
    if ok {
         fmt.Println(s)
    }
`

Answer (score 3):

[gist](https://gist.github.com/yaxinr/679976f1cde2a7b2925c30fa89b03eea)
invoke struct method with error handling

```
// Invoke - firstResult, err := Invoke(AnyStructInterface, MethodName, Params...)
func invoke(any interface{}, name string, args ...interface{}) (reflect.Value, error) {
    method := reflect.ValueOf(any).MethodByName(name)
    methodType := method.Type()
    numIn := methodType.NumIn()
    if numIn > len(args) {
        return reflect.ValueOf(nil), fmt.Errorf("Method %s must have minimum %d params. Have %d", name, numIn, len(args))
    }
    if numIn != len(args) && !methodType.IsVariadic() {
        return reflect.ValueOf(nil), fmt.Errorf("Method %s must have %d params. Have %d", name, numIn, len(args))
    }
    in := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))
    for i := 0; i < len(args); i++ {
        var inType reflect.Type
        if methodType.IsVariadic() && i >= numIn-1 {
            inType = methodType.In(numIn - 1).Elem()
        } else {
            inType = methodType.In(i)
        }
        argValue := reflect.ValueOf(args[i])
        if !argValue.IsValid() {
            return reflect.ValueOf(nil), fmt.Errorf("Method %s. Param[%d] must be %s. Have %s", name, i, inType, argValue.String())
        }
        argType := argValue.Type()
        if argType.ConvertibleTo(inType) {
            in[i] = argValue.Convert(inType)
        } else {
            return reflect.ValueOf(nil), fmt.Errorf("Method %s. Param[%d] must be %s. Have %s", name, i, inType, argType)
        }
    }
    return method.Call(in)[0], nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [great](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19721562/9935654). I added the return value example for it.

```golang
package main
import ("fmt";"math/rand";"reflect";"time")

// Invoke call the struct method and store the return values in a []reflect.Value
// return value example
// assume return value: (int, time.Time, error)
// var r []reflect.Value
// => r[0].interface() // for int
// => r[1].interface() // for time.Time
// => r[2].interface() // for error
// and so on.
func Invoke(obj any, name string, args ...any) []reflect.Value {
    inputs := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))
    for i, _ := range args {
        inputs[i] = reflect.ValueOf(args[i])
    }
    return reflect.ValueOf(obj).MethodByName(name).Call(inputs)
}

type Score struct{}

func (s Score) IsExcellent(score int) (bool, error) {
    if score < 0 {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("invalid score")
    }
    if score > 90 {
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, nil
}

func (s Score) Generate(min, max int) (int, time.Time) {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return rand.Intn(max-min) + min, time.Now()
}

func main() {
    s := Score{}
    values1 := Invoke(s, "IsExcellent", 95)
    values2 := Invoke(s, "IsExcellent", -5)
    for _, values := range [][]reflect.Value{values1, values2} {
        if len(values) > 0 {
            err := values[1].Interface()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.(error))
                continue
            }
            fmt.Println(values[0].Bool())
        }
    }
    values := Invoke(Score{}, "Generate", 0, 101)
    randNumber := values[0].Int()
    createTime := values[1].Interface().(time.Time) // It's better to check `values[1].Interface()` equal to nil first before you do assertion.
    fmt.Println(randNumber, createTime)
}
```

<kbd>[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/84d_hgsxcP3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Log struct {
    Path  string
    Level string
}

func (l *Log) Conversion(i interface{}) {

    if data, ok := i.(*Log); ok {
        if data != nil {
            if len(data.Path) > 0 {
                l.Path = data.Path
            }
            if len(data.Level) > 0 {
                l.Level = data.Level
            }
        }
    }
}

type Storage struct {
    Type       string
    ServerList []string
}

func (s *Storage) Conversion(i interface{}) {

   if data, ok := i.(*Storage); ok {
        if data != nil {
            if len(data.Type) > 0 {
                s.Type = data.Type
            }
        }
    }
}

type Server struct {
    LogConfig     *Log
    StorageConfig *Storage
}

func main() {
    def := Server{
        LogConfig: &Log{
            Path:  "/your/old/log/path/",
            Level: "info",
        },
        StorageConfig: &Storage{
            Type:       "zookeeper",
            ServerList: []string{"127.0.0.1:2181"},
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(def)
    cur := Server{
        LogConfig: &Log{
            Path:  "/your/new/log/path/",
            Level: "debug",
        },
        StorageConfig: &Storage{
            Type:       "etcd",
            ServerList: []string{"127.0.0.1:2379"},
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(cur)

    defV := reflect.ValueOf(def)
    curV := reflect.ValueOf(cur)
    for k := 0; k < defV.NumField(); k++ {
        in := make([]reflect.Value, 1)
        in[0] = reflect.ValueOf(curV.Field(k).Interface())
        defV.Field(k).MethodByName("Conversion").Call(in)
    }

    fmt.Println(def.LogConfig)
    fmt.Println(def.StorageConfig)
}
```