# How to send a message to an object in Golang? (.send() equivalent in go)

Tags: go

I am a Go beginner, coming from Ruby land.

In Ruby, you could do something like this.

`Time.send("now")` is equivalent to `Time.now`, as you are sending the message `now` to the object `Time`

Is there something similar in golang?

Comment: I'm afraid Go is neither a dynamic nor a classically object oriented language. A lot of things are different here.

Comment: I don't think you've accurately described `send`. It looks like the first argument of `send` needs to be a symbol not a string.

Comment: @deft_code It works with both `Time.send("now")`, `Time.send(:now)` -- also ruby isn't picky about these kinds of things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other suggested, you can do it yourself by mapping strings to functions, but the strong-typing nature of Go makes it difficult to translate `.send` directly into Go.

You can still use reflection if you really need to access a field or method by name:

```
import "reflect"
import "fmt"

type A struct {
    Number int
}

func (a *A) Method(i int) int {
    return a.Number + i;
}

func main() {
    a := &A{Number: 1}
    // Direct access
    fmt.Printf("Direct -> Nb: %d, Nb + 2: %d\n", a.Number, a.Method(2));

    v := reflect.ValueOf(*a)
    vp := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    field := v.FieldByName("Number")
    meth := vp.MethodByName("Method")
    args := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(2)}
    // Reflection access
    fmt.Printf("Reflect -> Nb: %d, Nb + 2: %d\n", 
               field.Interface().(int), 
               meth.Call(args)[0].Interface().(int))
}
```

Outputs:

```
Direct -> Nb: 1, Nb + 2: 3
Reflect -> Nb: 1, Nb + 2: 3
```

[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/bRK-NChSt6)

Note however:

1. How cumbersome that is. Usually, performing a map as suggested by @ANisus is a more idiomatic way of doing
2. You still have to perform your conversions in the end.

Using the `reflect` packages changes your typed variable into more flexible `Value` objects, but these are *very* cumbersome to use in practice. It is usually better if you can find a way to express your intent without relying on reflection.

Also note that here, we had to use two `Value`s, one for `a` (a pointer to `A`) for the method, and one for `*a` (a `A` structure) for the field. Trying to get a method defined with a pointer receiver with a non-pointer `Value` (or conversely, trying to obtain a field via a pointer `Value`) will result in a panic. More generally, due to the dynamic nature of reflected `Value`s and its difference with the usual typed Go, expect a lot of convenience features (such as automatic referencing/dereferencing) to be absent on `Value`s.

Also, expect quite a bit of runtime panics while debugging, as it is the only way for dynamic `Value` calls to fail !

Reference: [the reflect package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)

Answer (score 9):

There is no built in way of calling an arbitrary function from a string in Go.

You can create something similar by registering functions to a map[string].
A working example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var m = map[string]func(){
    "now":  func() { fmt.Println("The time is now") },
    "then": func() { fmt.Println("Once upon a time") },
}

func main() {
    cmd := "then"
    m[cmd]()
}
```

[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/KHnOy6ecvY)

There is also the possibility of using reflection in order to call a method by name. You can look at the `reflect` package for `MethodByName` and `Call`. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103617/call-a-struct-and-its-method-by-name-in-go) Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

No. Work your way through http://tour.golang.org/ and http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html and you will have a proper understanding of how method invocation works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using `reflect`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

// Send sends a message to(calls a method of) obj, with args.
// The return value of the method call is set to ret and any error to err.
func Send(obj interface{}, method string, args ...interface{}) (ret []reflect.Value, err error) {
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            err = fmt.Errorf("%v", e)
        }
    }()
    objValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
    argsValue := make([]reflect.Value, 0, len(args))
    for _, arg := range args {
        argsValue = append(argsValue, reflect.ValueOf(arg))
    }
    mtd := objValue.MethodByName(method)
    if !mtd.IsValid() {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%v does not have a method %v", reflect.TypeOf(obj), method)
    }
    ret = mtd.Call(argsValue)
    return
}

// Then do some tests.

type A struct {
    value int
}

func (a A) Value() int {
    return a.value
}

func (a *A) SetValue(v int) {
    a.value = v
}

func main() {
    var (
        ret []reflect.Value
        err error
    )
    // StdOut.WriteString("Hello, World!\n")
    _, err = Send(os.Stdout, "WriteString", "Hello, World!\n")
    handleError(err)

    var a = &A{100}

    // ret = a.Value()
    ret, err = Send(a, "Value")
    handleError(err)
    fmt.Printf("Return value is: %v\n", ret[0].Int())

    // a.SetValue(200)
    _, err = Send(a, "SetValue", 200)
    handleError(err)

    // ret = a.Value()
    ret, err = Send(a, "Value")
    handleError(err)
    fmt.Printf("Return value is: %v", ret[0].Int())
}

func handleError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I based my code on [this description](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send) of send.

```rb
class Klass
  def hello(*args)
    "Hello " + args.join(' ')
  end
end
k = Klass.new
k.send :hello, "gentle", "readers"   #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```

http://play.golang.org/p/lXlzBf_fGZ

```
package main

import "strings"

type Klass struct{}

func (k Klass) Hello(args ...string) string {
    return "Hello " + strings.Join(args, " ")
}

func (k Klass) Send(symbol func(Klass, ...string) string, args ...string) string {
    return symbol(k, args...)
}

func main() {
    k := new(Klass)
    k.Send(Klass.Hello, "gentle", "readers") //=> "Hello gentle readers"
}
```

The big difference between the two is that Go's `Send` function is only implemented for `Klass` and only works on methods that take a variable number of strings as parameters and return a single string. This is because Go is a statically typed language where Ruby is dynamically typed. Go **does** support dynamic typing via the [reflect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) library, but it is an unpleasant experience and not the way general Go code is meant to be written.