# Using reflection to call a method and return a value

Tags: oop, reflection, methods, go

Using the question about [calling a method by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103617/call-a-struct-and-its-method-by-name-in-go) as a starting point, I wanted to call a method by name and actually do something with the value.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type T struct{}

func (t *T) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}

type MyStruct struct {
    id int
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (t *T) Bar(ms *MyStruct, p *Person) int {
    return p.Age

}

func main() {
    var t *T
    reflect.ValueOf(t).MethodByName("Foo").Call([]reflect.Value{})
    var ans int
    ans = reflect.ValueOf(t).MethodByName("Bar").Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(&MyStruct{15}), reflect.    ValueOf(&Person{"Dexter", 15})})
}
```

[Playground link, http://play.golang.org/p/e02-KpdQ_P](http://play.golang.org/p/e02-KpdQ_P)

However, I get the following error:

```
prog.go:30: cannot use reflect.ValueOf(t).MethodByName("Bar").Call([]reflect.Value literal) (type []reflect.Value) as type int in assignment
 [process exited with non-zero status]
```

What should I do differently to actually return a value? I tried using type conversion and making it an `int`, but the compiler said that it couldn't `[]reflect.Value`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53293158/1359764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Call` returns `[]reflect.Value` which is a slice. You need to get an element from the slice in order to do the type conversion. Once you have a `reflect.Value` instance you can call `Int()` to get the value as an int64.

```
var ans int64
ans = reflect.ValueOf(t).MethodByName("Bar").Call([]reflect.Value{
    reflect.ValueOf(&MyStruct{15}), 
    reflect.ValueOf(&Person{"Dexter", 15})})[0].Int()
fmt.Println(ans)
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/TwWxRlRyDk)