# Reflection: Struct by string

Tags: reflection, go

Let's assume I have this struct with a method:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct {
}

func (a *MyStruct) AAction() {
    fmt.Println("Hello a")
}
```

Now, if I want to call the method "AAction" by string, I can use reflection (this works):

```
func main() {
    reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(MyStruct{})).MethodByName("AAction").Call([]reflect.Value{})
}
```

The problem is, that I don't want to use MyStruct{} as an expression, but as a string. Of course this doesn't work:

```
func main() {
    theStruct := "MyStruct"
    theAction := "AAction"
    reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(theStruct)).MethodByName(theAction).Call([]reflect.Value{})
}
```

because reflect.Typeof(theStruct) would be a string. 
I tried reading through the documentation, sadly, I can't find anything very useful.

I found this similar question: [Call a Struct and its Method by name in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103617/call-a-struct-and-its-method-by-name-in-go)

 Under the accepted question, the OP asks:

> The issue in my case Is I cant not declare t is typed T, its must be some how I can declare t typed T by the name of T is string "T"

which gets answered by

> [...] I would suggest to match the name against the string "T" somewhere in your code [...]

which doesn't solve the problem, as I would still need to call `MyStruct{}` somewhere.

The question is: is there any way to use a struct by giving the name as a string? (without manually mapping the the name of the struct to the struct)

Working version with using `reflect.TypeOf(MyStruct{})`:
[PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/NqVIE07EoN)
Not working version, obviously calling the method on a string: [PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/ZbdKmCvNPB)

Comment: Have a registry where you register each type by its name. Then consult the registry with that name and pull out whatever you registered. A bit how image decoders register them in the image package. Don't do reflection.

Comment: @Volker I'm aware that I shouldn't, but the question was: _could_ I do reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you can't. The answer is: you could *not*. There is no builtin or pre-initialized registry of type names.

To get started with reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package), you need a value (of the type in question). Based on a `string` (`string` name of the type), you can't acquire a value of that type, so you can't get started.

If you do want to do what you want only by a `string` type name, you need to build your own "registry" prior to doing what you want.

Comment: Sorry that it took me long to accept the answer. I was hoping for someone to shout "NOPE"