# How do you invoke a method on the dynamic type of a variable?

Tags: go

I found two questions and read them:

- [Reflection: Struct by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424907/reflection-struct-by-string/36425480#36425480)
- [Call a Struct and its Method by name in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103617/call-a-struct-and-its-method-by-name-in-go)

But I still don't understand why I tried mapping an Object that got error:

`./aaa.go:21: m.Action undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`

```
type MyStruct struct {
}

func (a *MyStruct) Action() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}

func main() {
    var Mstruct map[string]interface{}
    Mstruct = make(map[string]interface{}, 100)
    Mstruct["MyStruct"] = &MyStruct{}
    m := Mstruct["MyStruct"]
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(m)) // *main.MyStruct
    m.Action()
}
```

This always works in dynamic language, so I miss something in static language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
m := Mstruct["MyStruct"]
```

is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). The [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) states

> If a type is present, each variable is given that type. Otherwise,
>   each variable is given the type of the corresponding initialization
>   value in the assignment.

Since a type is not present in that expression, the variable `m` is given the type of the corresponding initialization value, `Mstruct["MyStruct"]`. That type is `interface{}`.

Based on your current imports, the method set of `interface{}` is empty. There's nothing you can invoke on a value of ype `interface{}`. Therefore the compiler rejects

```
m.Action()
```

You seem to want to use `m` as a method receiver based on its dynamic type, `*MyStruct`. You can do that with a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). For example

```
dynamic := m.(*MyStruct)
dynamic.Action()
```

The specification states

> If the type assertion holds, the value of the expression is the value
>   stored in `x` and its type is `T`.

Its type here is `*MyStruct` which is the receiver type of your `Action` method. You can therefore invoke the method with the variable `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

```
func main() {
    var Mstruct map[string]interface{}
    Mstruct = make(map[string]interface{}, 100)
    Mstruct["MyStruct"] = &MyStruct{}
    m := Mstruct["MyStruct"].(*MyStruct) //This is a type assertion
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(m)) // *main.MyStruct
    m.Action()
}
```

Use type assertion.  After you assert that it is not nil and of the specified type, you can treat it as that type.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

https://play.golang.org/p/bJib9g7kDY